# How to rename all the files using shell script?

Tags: shell

I have hundreds of file of same format. I want to rename the files by taking the first six characters and the extension.

Following code extracts the first 6 characters... I am displaying them

```
     for i in *.png; do echo $i | awk '{ print substr($0, 0, 7 )}'; done
```

I am unable to concat the extension. Could somebody help. It will be great if the script could be completed with mv command.

Thanks

Comment: so all your files has at least 6 chars + ext like: 123456.png?

Comment: Yes, and they're all unique within 6 characters or the duplicates don't matter.  The question clearly implies that.  It would be interesting to know how confident the questioner is that this is actually the case.

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that every file-name has at least six characters before the extension, you can write

```
for file in *.png ; do mv "$file" "${file:0:6}.png" ; done
```

Comment: This is really cool. Wonder if there is any book containing all these cool hacks. +1

Comment: @JaypalSingh: It's all in [the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html). It's . . . not exactly "light reading", but if you work a lot in Bash, it's well worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Do the piping outside the loop body, if you continue to use `awk`:

```
for i in *.png; do echo $i; done |
awk '{ print "mv $0 " substr($0, 0, 7) ".png"}' |
sh -vn
```

The revised `awk` prints the `mv` commands.  When you're happy it is going to do the right job, replace the `-vn` with `-x` (or with nothing).

This will work with pretty much any shell.  If you're using `bash` specifically, then there are built-in string manipulations to do the job you need - see the answer by [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) for one possible technique.  There are a myriad other options available; some systems have a capable `rename` command (others have a less capable version).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but isn't the `for i in *.png; do echo $i; done` more succinctly written as `echo *.png`?

Comment: The difference between the loop and a single `echo` is that the loop places each 'word' on its own line, whereas the single `echo` places all the words on a single line.  You could write an `awk` script to deal with that, too, but you'd have an explicit loop over the number of fields in the input record.  I have a trivial C program that echoes arguments one per line, and find it very useful. How trivial?  This trivial: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { while (*++argv != 0) puts(*argv); return 0; }` and it needs `#include <stdio.h>` too, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of one line vs multiple lines. Okay, then, lets use the more posixy `printf '%s\n' *.png` :-)

Comment: You may; I'm happy not doing so, but that's because I learned shell a long (long, long) time ago and what I wrote above would work (at the shell level) in really old systems as well as modern ones.  (The original awk did not have a `substr()` command.)  Basically, leave fossils like me gently fossilizing, and adapt to suit your own purposes.